# How do I interpret the domain & range of the KDB function `xbar`?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to understand the documentation here:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/xbar/#domain-and-range

I've got some standard minute data

```
t                             o       h      l      c       v      n   vw       sym
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015.12.01D14:30:00.000000000 44.14   44.14  44.02  44.1    126762 337 44.10188 XLK
2015.12.01D14:31:00.000000000 44.09   44.12  44.08  44.11   17104  123 44.09911 XLK
2015.12.01D14:32:00.000000000 44.12   44.12  44.1   44.1    232106 663 44.1154  XLK
2015.12.01D14:33:00.000000000 44.1    44.11  44.1   44.11   72177  260 44.10674 XLK
```

Which I'm trying to group by 5-min intervals:

```
select max o by t.date, 5 xbar t.time from xlk

date       time        | o
-----------------------| -------
2015.12.01 14:30:00.000| 44.14
2015.12.01 14:31:00.000| 44.09
2015.12.01 14:32:00.000| 44.12
```

So first, these didn't come out as 5-min bars, so that's an issue. My real question is though, can I do an `xbar` directly on the `t` column (rather than do a joint `by` clause)?

If yes - is this cryptic documentation I've linked telling me how to do this?

Comment: Made the kx librarian aware of your comments on the documentation. Feel free to suggest what you think is a clearer alternative

Comment: In the Q Reference the Domain & Range sections tabulate the range (result) datatypes for every combination of domain (argument) datatypes. What can be done to make this clearer? Stephen Taylor (KX Librarian)

Comment: @SJT I think I get the domain bit now (e.g. if I provide types `h,h` as arguments, I'd get an `i` back). I think I understand the 'range' part to be just the possible output types of xbar. I think I'd provide a single line example, as I just did, explaining how to use the table.

Thanks for ArrayCast by the way; it's my most listened to podcast!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the first part, 5 minute bars can be achieved by using `t.minute` instead of `t.time`:

```
q)select max o by t.date, 5 xbar t.minute from xlk
date       minute| o
-----------------| -----
2015.12.01 14:30 | 44.14
/ example 1 minute bars
q)select max o by t.date, 1 xbar t.minute from xlk
date       minute| o
-----------------| -----
2015.12.01 14:30 | 44.14
2015.12.01 14:31 | 44.09
2015.12.01 14:32 | 44.12
2015.12.01 14:33 | 44.1
```

To use `xbar` directly with your time column of type timestamp the 5 minutes must be given in type of timespan.

```
q)select max o by 0D00:05 xbar t from xlk
t                            | o
-----------------------------| -----
2015.12.01D14:30:00.000000000| 44.14
/ example 1 minute bars again to highlight
q)select max o by 0D00:01 xbar t from xlk
t                            | o
-----------------------------| -----
2015.12.01D14:30:00.000000000| 44.14
2015.12.01D14:31:00.000000000| 44.09
2015.12.01D14:32:00.000000000| 44.12
2015.12.01D14:33:00.000000000| 44.1
```

`xbar` works on the underlying integer value for the datatype. For the time datatype that is 5 millisecond bars.

```
q)5 xbar 14:30:00.123 14:30:00.127
14:30:00.120 14:30:00.125

/ equivlant xbar on integer values
q)`int$14:30:00.123 14:30:00.127
52200123 52200127i
q)5 xbar `int$14:30:00.123 14:30:00.127
52200120 52200125
q)`time$5 xbar `int$14:30:00.123 14:30:00.127
14:30:00.120 14:30:00.125
```

I think the [documentation linked](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/xbar/#domain-and-range) just describes which datatypes can form the arguments to `xbar` and what the datatype of the output will be.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Thomas' answer, it helps to understand what "integer math" means for the different levels of time(stamp) because they're not all the same.

```
q)11:25+1  /in context of minute type, integer 1 means 1 minute
11:26
q)11:25:10+1 /in context of second type, integer 1 means 1 second
11:25:11
q)11:25:10.123+1 /in context of time type, integer 1 means 1 millisecond
11:25:10.124
q)11:25:10.123456789+1 /in context of timespan type, integer 1 means 1 nanosecond
0D11:25:10.123456790
q)2022.10.27T18:00:08.431+1 /in context of datetime type, integer 1 means 1 day
2022.10.28T18:00:08.431
q)2022.12.31D11:25:10.123456789+1 /in context of timespan type, integer 1 means 1 nanosecond
2022.12.31D11:25:10.123456790
```

Your example used integer 5 in the context of a time type so you were xbar'ing at the millisecond level. You have to scale your "5" up to the required level that you're trying to aggregate (in your case minutes). A simple way to scale this up would be something like:

```
q)select max o by t.date,(`int$00:05:00.0) xbar t.time from xlk
date       time        | o
-----------------------| -
2015.12.01 14:30:00.000| 4
2015.12.01 14:35:00.000| 9
```

or

```
q)select max o by t.date,(5*60*1000) xbar t.time from xlk
date       time        | o
-----------------------| -
2015.12.01 14:30:00.000| 4
2015.12.01 14:35:00.000| 9
```

5 times 60 seconds times 1000 milliseconds (aka 5 minutes).

For your final question - yes you could do it directly to the t column but then you need to scale slightly differently as per the above

```
q)select max o by 0D00:05 xbar t from xlk
t                            | o
-----------------------------| -
2015.12.01D14:30:00.000000000| 4
2015.12.01D14:35:00.000000000| 9
```

or

```
q)select max o by (5*60*1000*1000*1000) xbar t from xlk
t                            | o
-----------------------------| -
2015.12.01D14:30:00.000000000| 4
2015.12.01D14:35:00.000000000| 9
```